# Proguard and Android - no size reduction seen

Tags: android, apk, proguard

I have a library project which refers two other library projects (Google Play Services and Appcompat). The referencing project has no code just resources. All the code is in this library project. I added proguard configuration for my library project hoping to reduce the size of my binary. It compiles and generates the signed apk fine using ant build. But I see no reduction in binary size. Its exactly the same size as it was without proguard. Also obfuscation occurs only for few of the classes , not all.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out myself. I configured proguard for the referencing project instead of configuring it in the library. All referenced libraries were automatically taken care of and i was able to shrink the size of final apk by about 30%.

Answer (score 0):

obfuscation does not occur for all classes, some classes are skipped as they need to remain (normal) mainly, the views, and other classes that need to be accessed by external components

also check Proguard config file,
you some classes might be set as skipped by mistake.

Comment: I know it does not happen for all classes. But, out of my own written classes i can easily guess which ones will get obfuscated because i know them in and out. And they are not happening. There are two identical classes, with minimal difference. One got obfuscated and one did not. That's strange.

Comment: Also, not a singly byte of size reduction? That surely means i'm going wrong somewhere ...

Comment: thats strange, is any of them extends or implements some other class? some rules might be tricky in the proguard.cfg file,

Comment: Question: Does proguard also strip unused code from libraries? majority of the size is because of the libraries, my own code is only 1/4th. is there something additional i need to configure to take care of it?